# My JavaScript seems to crash when I instantiate a new Date Object

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript with this being my first little app. I am working on this Calendar / Date Time Picker program. I seem to have entered a nightmare scenario where the app crashes and I cannot figure out what is doing the crashing. After some primitive sleuthing (ie successive document.writes to pinpoint the line which kills it, I seem to have narrowed in on a very innocent line of code:

```
month_start = new Date(this.Year, this.Month, 1);
```

this.Year and this.Month are attributes of the class/parent function. I checked them and they both contain valid values at this point. I placed a document.write before this line and it displays, but immediately following this line the program is not responsive and does not display a document.write.

Is there some kind of JavaScript 101 mistake I am making here?

This line is inside a pretty small function. The whole function looks like this:

```
function Display_Calendar_Week(x, month_days){
ds = '';
d=0;
//for the first day of the month, start at the appropriate day of the week
if(x==1)
{
    //first date of current month and year

    month_start = new Date(this.Year, this.Month, 1);

    d = month_start.getDay();
}
for(j=0;j<7;j++)
{
    if( (j<d) || (x > month_days))
    {
        ds +=('<div class="Calendar_Day_Square_Empty"></div>');
    }
    else
    {
        if((x==RightNow_Date) && (RightNow_Month==this.Month) && (RightNow_Year==this.Year))
        {

            ds +=('<div class="Calendar_Day_Square_Today" onClick="'+this.InstanceName+'.Select_Date(\''+ this.PageElement +'\', '+ this.Year +', '+ this.Month +', '+ x +');">' + x + '</div>');
        }
        else if((x==this.Selected_Date) && (this.Selected_Month==this.Month) && (this.Selected_Year==this.Year))
        {
            ds +=('<div class="Calendar_Day_Square_Selected" onClick="'+this.InstanceName+'.Select_Date(\''+ this.PageElement +'\', '+ this.Year +', '+ this.Month +', '+ x +');">' + x + '</div>');
        }
        else
            ds +=('<div class="Calendar_Day_Square" onClick="'+this.InstanceName+'.Select_Date(\''+ this.PageElement +'\', '+ this.Year +', '+ this.Month +', '+ x +');">' + x + '</div>');
        x++;
    }
}
return [x, ds];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your function, `this.Year` and `this.Month` are `undefined`. You never assign them any values, and this is why the `new Date(undefined, undefined, 1)` stops the execution. The same goes for the `this.PageElement`, `this.Selected_Month`, etc - but the script never gets there.

And a few tips: consider using `var` when declaring variables - this way, they won't be in the global (`window`) scope; also, string concatenation is way slower than building an array of strings and joining it: `['a', 'b', 'c'].join('');`

Comment: The [x, y, z].join(''); part is optimization, so it should be done at the end [in my opinion, it is ugly, while it is also premature-optimization]

Comment: IMHO it's cleaner than concatenation - consider
var html = [];
html.push('<div class="');
html.push(divCssClass); // etc.
- it makes the code much more readable, especially if you wrap it in a chainable stringBuilder.